# Error 404 flight inspiration search test mode

Tags: amadeus

Im getting error 404 while searching flight inspiration search in test mode. Even is happening in the "try ot out" feature in the official web from Amadeus.

Answer (score 0):

There is a technical issue with the Flight Inspiration API in the test environment. If you need to use the API before it's fixed, you can move your app to the production environment where it works as expected. In this environment you will receive a [free amount](https://developers.amadeus.com/pricing) of transactions each month just like in test.